# Ошибка при запуске телеграм-фильм-бота

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Подскажите, в чем причина ошибки?

При запуске **app.py** выдает ошибку на миллисекунду и закрывает пайтон:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\xdesantiago\app.py”, line 3, in
> V from loader import dp, bot, admin_id
> File “C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\xdesantiago\loader.py”, line 3, in
> from config import token, admin_id
> File "C:\Users\bogda\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\xdesantiago\config.py”, line 2, in
> admin_id=int(ID)
>
> NameError: name 'ID' is not defined. Did you mean: "id"?

Comment: Если прочитать ошибку - можно понять, что проблема в обращении к несуществующей переменной ID.

Comment: Можете прикрепить код? У вас видимо нету этой переменной

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `NameError: name 'ID' is not defined` указывает на то, что в вашем коде есть обращение к переменной ID, которая не была определена ранее. Это происходит в файле config.py, во второй строке: `admin_id=int(ID)`. Python не может найти переменную с таким именем. Убедитесь, то переменная ID определена в вашем коде. Если она находится в другом файле, убедитесь, что этот файл подключен. Для этого можно использовать конструкцию вида `import other_module` или `from other_module import ID`.

Comment: У меня прописана вторя строка и там вписан мой айди admin_id=int(мой id) но все равно не фуричыт

Comment: У вас в коде до 2 строки переменная `ID` упомянается?

Comment: В app.py ? или в config.py? в app.py упоминаеться в 3 строке а в config.py 2 строки 
вот
token='ну тут токен бота не буду светить ' 
admin_id=int(ID) - ну тут мой айди

Comment: В файле config.py, в строке `admin_id=int(ID)` происходит неудачная попытка обратиться к переменной с названием ID. Посмотрите внимательно на код и поищите, объявляется ли где-нибудь у вас переменная ID. Объявление переменной - это когда ей присваивается значение, например, `ID = 350`.  Если такой строки у вас нет, то либо её следует создать, либо сразу подставить нужное значение в строку `admin_id=int(нужное_значение)`.

Comment: Спасибо уже решил